# Cyclic connected graph vs acyclic connected graph use case

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, graph-theory

I have a graph with such structure and rules:

[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZAtz.png)

1. It is directed connected cyclic graph (direction from top to bottom nodes).
2. Any parent node can have 0, 1 or 2 children.
3. Child can have 1 or 2 parents (root node `n_id_1` has no parents).
4. There are left child and right child. Parent can have right child and not have left child or vice versa (see `n_id_9` and `n_id_2`).
5. If parent (`n_id_9`) has left branch (`n_id_3` - `n_id_8`) and no right branch, it always becomes parent of child of left branch (`n_id_11`).

At this point i see 2 solutions for data structure:

Option 1. Make a directed connected cyclic graph like this (most obvious way):

```
parent            children
   1                 2
   2                 3, 11
   3                 5, 6
   5                 9
   6                 4
   9                 10, 12
   4                 7
   12                8
   7                 8
   8                 11
```

I think that downside of this - hard to render and to maintain.

Option 2. Make a directed connected acyclic graph in which every parent can have 3 children: left, right and third (don't know how to call it better). So for example `n_id_2` has **left child** `n_id_3`, no **right child** and **third child** `n_id_11`. For missing children we should specify `null`.

```
parent            children (left, right, third)
   1                 2, null, null 
   2                 3, null, 11
   3                 5, 6, 8
   5                 9, null, null
   6                 4, null, null
   9                 null, 10, 12
   4                 7, null, null
   12                null, null, null
   7                 null, null, null
   8                 null, null, null
```

It is much easier to render and walk through data since now we have a tree without cycles. Downside of this i see - if for some reason specs would be changed - it might be harder to change. I prefer this one.

So the questions are:

1. Are there any other solutions?
2. What do you think about my provided solutions?

Thank you for reviewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on what operations you need to perform on your graph. From your comment, you only need to edit the graph and not perform any expensive computation, so take the representation that suits you better from the usability perspective.

Personally, I would go with your second solution, which seems more natural for a graph with such properties, I would only describe it a little different:
The graph can be represented as a sequence of **nodes**, each node may have a **left** and **right child branch** and a **successor** (which is what you called *third*). Both child branches are optional; no successor means the end of the sequence. A child branch is again a sequence of the same kind of nodes.

This gives you a simple recursive structure, which I find easy to reason about (YMMV, of course).

As a side note: this graph is not cyclic, only it's undirected counterpart is.

Comment: Operations i expect to do on this graph:

- Add a node to any part of graph;
- Delete node and all successors;
- Move branches, nodes.
No analysis or search is needed.